# How is an event passed in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Teaching myself `jQuery` and I came across the code below. I wanted to know how the event was passed through the anonymous function without creation.

```
$(function() 
{
   $("#cancelForm").on("click", function(e)
    {
      e.preventDefault();
      clearForm();
    }
 });
```

Comment: It's passed internally by `jQuery`. In simple terms, when they define the `on` method, they execute the function you give passing the event as an argument when the specified event is triggered.

Comment: @AngelPolitis in this scenario, I didn't see any instances of the event object.

Comment: In which scenario?

Comment: @AngelPolitis the function above

Comment: @AngelPolitis Ahhhhhh. I see! I checked the on method just like you said and noticed the fourth parameter in the API. So is the "Event" object implicit in the parameter?

Comment: The browser passes an appropriate event object into your handler function as the only parameter which you are receiving as `e` in this example.  In addition, the browser sets the value of `this` available within your handler, in most cases, to the element that triggered the event.

Comment: Yes @NewProgrammer. Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48434242/6313073). I have included an example definition of the `on` method, so that you can see how, _approximately_, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event instance is passed internally by `jQuery`. In simple terms, when they define their `on` method, they execute the function you give passing the event as an argument when the specified event is triggered.

**Example code:**

<sup>*(aiming to approximate how `on` would be defined)*</sup>

```
/* Definition of the 'on' method'. */
$.fn.on = function (eventType, callback) {
   /* Iterate over every element of the jQuery object. */
   for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
      /* Create an event listener for the currently iterated element. */
      this[i].addEventListener(eventType, function (e) {
         /* Execute the callback given passing the custom jQuery Event object to it. */
         callback($.Event(e));
      });
   }
});
```

---

**Notes:**

1. `$.fn` is the object where `jQuery` defines its prototype methods.
2. The `e` shown in the function passed to `addEventListener` is passed by the browser.

Comment: So is the "e" is the event object of the eventType being passed.

Comment: The `e` in your function is the value `$.Event(e)` returns. The `e` in mine is the native event the browser creates. Disclaimer: `e` is just a name; you can name it anything.

Comment: I see! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome @NewProgrammer. I'm glad I could help 

Comment: sorry.. I think i'm overthinking it, but is $.Event(e) the callback function?

Comment: No, `$.Event(e)` returns the `jQuery` event object you have named as `e` in your function. This event object is a more sophisticated version of the native one used by the browser and has extra data given by `jQuery`. The callback is the function you passed _(the second argument you pass to `on`)_. Inside `on`, this function is executed and is given one argument, the `jQuery` event object.

Comment: so the event object I name "e" holds the definition of the self defined stated in my example. When the button is clicked, the "click" event has been stated in the .on() and it'll return the event object that contains two method calls (preventDefault, clearForm) basically.

Comment: The two method calls you refer to are contained in the callback _(the function you pass)_, not the event. The event contains properties like the the coordinates of the mouse, its name etc. To understand what I mean about `jQuery Event Object`  and `Native Event Object`, use `console.log(e, e.originalEvent)` and check them out in your console.

Comment: Nevermind my last comment. My lightbulb turned on and fully understood your last comment! Sorry for the trouble!! Now I get it!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments the function you pass to `on()` as argument gets called inside `on()` where the event object is passed to your callback when the event actually occurs

Simplified example:

```js
function dummyOn( eventName, callback){
   // do internal stuff

   // call the function you created and pass `100` to it
   // in real on() this would get called when event occurs and pass the event object
   callback(100);
}


dummyOn('silly-event', function(e){
  console.log('e=', e);// 100 from what was passed to callback when it is called
})
```

Answer (score 0):

## [jQuery's event](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Event)

> jQuery's event system normalizes the event object according to W3C standards. The event object is guaranteed to be passed to the event handler (no checks for window.event required). It normalizes the target, relatedTarget, which, metaKey and pageX/Y properties and provides both `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()` methods.
>
> Those properties are all documented, and accompanied by examples, on the [Event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) page.
>
> The standard events in the Document Object Model are: blur, focus, load, resize, scroll, unload, beforeunload, **`click`**, `dblclick`, `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `mousemove`, `mouseover`, `mouseout`, `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`, `change`, `select`, `submit`, `keydown`, `keypress`, and `keyup`. Since the DOM event names have predefined meanings for some elements, using them for other purposes is not recommended. jQuery's event model can trigger an event by any name on an element, and it is propagated up the DOM tree to which that element belongs, if any.

You can check the caller function from Jquery calling the following `console.log(arguments.callee.caller.toString());` within your `click` event.

**That log prints the following:**

```
function (a) {
    a = n.event.fix(a);
    var b, c, e, f, g, h = [],
        i = d.call(arguments),
        j = (L.get(this, "events") || {})[a.type] || [],
        k = n.event.special[a.type] || {};
    if (i[0] = a, a.delegateTarget = this, !k.preDispatch || k.preDispatch.call(this, a) !== !1) {
        h = n.event.handlers.call(this, a, j), b = 0;
        while ((f = h[b++]) && !a.isPropagationStopped()) {
            a.currentTarget = f.elem, c = 0;
            while ((g = f.handlers[c++]) && !a.isImmediatePropagationStopped()) (!a.namespace_re || a.namespace_re.test(g.namespace)) && (a.handleObj = g, a.data = g.data, e = ((n.event.special[g.origType] || {}).handle || g.handler).apply(f.elem, i), void 0 !== e && (a.result = e) === !1 && (a.preventDefault(), a.stopPropagation()))
        }
        return k.postDispatch && k.postDispatch.call(this, a), a.result
    }
}
```

So, basically, JQuery injects the event object applying the necessary data for your logic.

```js
var clearForm = function() {
  console.log("Cleared");
};

$(function() {
  $("#cancelForm").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log(arguments.callee.caller.toString());

    e.preventDefault();
    clearForm();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='cancelForm'>
Cancel!
</button>
```